# JQuery Mini Menu - Navigation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

First post.  I've been web designing as a minor part of my role for quite some time and rely on using CSS templates extra.  Just to give you an idea of where I am.  I've recently utilised a template that contains a "mini menu" (a dropdown navigiation menu that only shows when the width of the page is narrow).  For some reason the navigation is not working.  If I select a page in the list, it does not navigate to the page.   This is probably a real newbie question, but I've tried playing with the code, and I can't for the life of me get it too work.

Below is the HTML I have.  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
   

    <title>Capita - BIM Level 2 Training</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/component.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
 
     
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.css">
   
      <script src="js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.menu').mobileMenu();
    });
  </script>
 
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="site-name">
        <a href="index.html"><p><img src="img/CapitaBanner.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
  <h1>BIM Level 2 Training</h1>
        <h2>This training is for internal use only</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <i class="fw-icon-th-list"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Modules</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">BIM4Capita</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mini-menu">
            <label>
          <select class="selectnav">
            <option value="#" selected="">Home</option>
            <option value="#">About</option>
            <option value="#">→ Another action</option>
            <option value="#">→ Something else here</option>
            <option value="#">→ Another action</option>
            <option value="#">→ Something else here</option>
            <option value="#">Services</option>
            <option value="#">Work</option>
            <option value="#">Contact</option>
          </select>
          </label>
          </div>
    </div>


   
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="featured-block">
        <!-- Example row of columns -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="block">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <a href="WhatIsBIM.html"><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
              <div class="caption">
                <h1>What is BIM?</h1>
                <p>In this module we will explore what BIM is, what BIM level 2 is and what it is not.<br><br></p>
                <a class="btn" href="whatisbim.html">more</a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="block">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h1>Benefits of BIM</h1>
                      <p>In this module we will explore the benefits of BIM when it is deployed fully on a project for both Capita and our client.</p>
                      <a class="btn" href="#">more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="block">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <a href="BIMTech.html"><img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h1>BIM Technology</h1>
                    <p>In this module we explore some of the technologies available to achieve the BIM Benefits.<br><br></p>
                    <a class="btn" href="BIMTech.html">more</a>
                  </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="block">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="caption">
                <h1>BIM Workflow</h1>
                <p>In this modules we explore the changes to project workflow that arise from implementing BIM.<br><br></p>
                <a class="btn" href="#">more</a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="block">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="img/img9.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="caption">
                <h1>Capita Examples</h1>
                <p>In this module we review examples of projects within Capita that have already used the BIM process.<br><br></p>
                <a class="btn" href="#">more</a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          
        
          
            
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      


   <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.mi
    
  </body>
</html>
```

The JS folder contains,

- bootstrap.js
- html5shiv.js
- jquery-1.9.1.js
- modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js
- respond.min.js

I get the following errors when using Inspect in Google Chrome;

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
  (Not Found)
- index.html:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
     at index.html:28 /favicon.ico
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure since your code is not complete here, but I think you are using document.ready, before jQuery is loaded. Your

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.menu').mobileMenu();
    });
    </script>
```

must be at the end of the document, after you imported all your libraries. And jQuery has to be the very first one of the list (even before jquery.mobilemenu), since the others will use it.

You can open the console to check if there is an error like $ is unknown, that means either your code or the libraries are loaded before jQuery.

Here an updated version of your code with the librairies in the right order.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <title>Capita - BIM Level 2 Training</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/component.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">


     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="site-name">
        <a href="index.html"><p><img src="img/CapitaBanner.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
        <h1>BIM Level 2 Training</h1>
        <h2>This training is for internal use only</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <i class="fw-icon-th-list"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Modules</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">BIM4Capita</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mini-menu">
            <label>
          <select class="selectnav">
            <option value="#" selected="">Home</option>
            <option value="#">About</option>
            <option value="#">→ Another action</option>
            <option value="#">→ Something else here</option>
            <option value="#">→ Another action</option>
            <option value="#">→ Something else here</option>
            <option value="#">Services</option>
            <option value="#">Work</option>
            <option value="#">Contact</option>
          </select>
          </label>
          </div>
    </div>



    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="featured-block">
        <!-- Example row of columns -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="block">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <a href="WhatIsBIM.html"><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
              <div class="caption">
                <h1>What is BIM?</h1>
                <p>In this module we will explore what BIM is, what BIM level 2 is and what it is not.<br><br></p>
                <a class="btn" href="whatisbim.html">more</a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="block">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="caption">
                      <h1>Benefits of BIM</h1>
                      <p>In this module we will explore the benefits of BIM when it is deployed fully on a project for both Capita and our client.</p>
                      <a class="btn" href="#">more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="block">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <a href="BIMTech.html"><img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h1>BIM Technology</h1>
                    <p>In this module we explore some of the technologies available to achieve the BIM Benefits.<br><br></p>
                    <a class="btn" href="BIMTech.html">more</a>
                  </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="block">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="caption">
                <h1>BIM Workflow</h1>
                <p>In this modules we explore the changes to project workflow that arise from implementing BIM.<br><br></p>
                <a class="btn" href="#">more</a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="block">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="img/img9.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="caption">
                <h1>Capita Examples</h1>
                <p>In this module we review examples of projects within Capita that have already used the BIM process.<br><br></p>
                <a class="btn" href="#">more</a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>





          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>




   <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.menu').mobileMenu();
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Nico, really appreciate you taking the time

Not sure what the "console"? 

It appears that that script is indeed already in place under were the libraries are loaded in.

You say my code is not complete.  Could I post anything else to make it clear as to what the issue is?  

Many thanks,

Comment: If you are in chrome press f12 to open the console. You need it open all the times when you are writing javascript so you can see any errors. Check if there is any errors in the console, if so post them here so I can help you !

Comment: Thanks Nico, these errors are, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
index.html:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.html:28
/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: $ is not defined at index.htm means your are using jquery before it's loaded (maybe a path is wrong cf the first error).

Can you send the code from <head> to <body> and the end with the <script> till the </body> ?

Comment: I've added the full HTML to the original post.   Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer with the fixed code, it should work now. It was the order of your import. You always have to insert jQuery first, and after the plugin and your code.

Comment: Thanks I now get the following error, index.html:159 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mobileMenu is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:159)
    at c (jquery-1.9.1.js:1)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.js:1)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.9.1.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.H (jquery-1.9.1.js:1)

Comment: It means the function is not founded but it's probably in your plugin : js/jquery.mobilemenu.js (you had a typo on your html the line <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script> was not complete (I edited my answer to fix that too check if your code is right there).

Comment: It looks like there was also a type in mobilemenu.  The funtion is all lowercase, but the script referred to  $('.menu').mobileMenu(); with a capital letter.   I now have a new issue.  The menu is at the top of the page and the navigation is still not working.  I may give up :-)

Comment: Thanks again Nico. I was fumbling in the dark a bit.  A lot to learn.  But I really appreciate you taking the time to try to help a newbie.

Comment: No problem, everyone started one day! If you create a complete jsfiddle with all the code and the dependancies I'll try to check it!